# How to configure Multiple SQS JMS Listeners for SpringBoot.?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs

I have 2 AWS SQS in which one contains Activities and other one contains Attachment info, I have JmsSqsListener and ActivitySqsConfig as below.

Using DefaultMessageListenerContainer I'm able to configure only one JmsSqsListener at a time either for Activity or for Attachment, but I want to configure JmsSqsListener for both SQS and DefaultMessageListenerContainer don't allow me do that. I also configure two different JmsSqsListener configuration using different classes but even that didn't work. It's just listening to one queue only.

```
@Configuration
public class JmsSqsListener {

    @Value("${aws.access.key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.secret.key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${aws.queue.region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${leaks.activity.queue}")
    private String activityQueue;

    @Value("${leaks.attachment.queue}")
    private String attachmentQueue;

    @Autowired
    private ActivityEngine activityListener;

    @Autowired
    private AttachmentEngine attachmentListener;   // How to add Listener for attachmentQueue

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer() {
        SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(),
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider));
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        dmlc.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
        dmlc.setDestinationName(activityQueue);// Also want to add attachmentQueue
        dmlc.setMessageListener(activityListener);  // Also want to add attachmentListener

        return dmlc;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate createJMSTemplate() {
        SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(),
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider));

        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(sqsConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(queueName);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(false);

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    private final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
            return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh() { }
    };
}
```

SQS Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SqsConfig {

    @Value("${aws.access.key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.secret.key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${aws.queue.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Value("${aws.queue.region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${leaks.activity.queue}")
    private String activityQueue;

    @Value("${leaks.attachment.queue}")
    private String attachmentQueue;

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQS createSQSClient() {
        AmazonSQSClientBuilder builder = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider);
        builder.setEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, region));
        AmazonSQS amazonSQSClient = builder.build();
        amazonSQSClient.createQueue(activityQueue); // want to create attachmentQueue also

        return amazonSQSClient;
    }

    private final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
            return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh() { }
    };
}
```

Please help me to configure JMS Listeners, so that 
1) ActivityEngine can listen to activityQueue
and same time
2) AttachmentEngine can listen to attachmentQueue;

Comment: Have you considered just using the JMS API directly rather than trying to force Spring components to do what you want? The JMS API isn't complex.

Comment: No, I haven't work with on JMS API and neither know about JMS & SpringBoot integration. if you know any documentation please suggest me.